# Screen transition in Tizen on button click

Tags: tizen

How to make a transition from one form to other on a button click in `Tizen`. Can anyone post a code snippet for that? I have a button on screen and yet other form, how to make a change in ui on click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a tutorial in official docs: https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/tutorials/ui_tutorial/task_uicontrolanimator.htm

I think, this one is exactly your case: https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/tutorials/ui_tutorial/task_uicontrolanimator_transition.htm

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [Tizen::Ui::Scenes::SceneManager](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1Ui_1_1Scenes_1_1SceneManager.html) to make such transitions. You can read more about scene management [here](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/guide/ui/scene_management.htm). There is Tizen sample application called [SceneManagement Sample](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/sample_descriptions/scenemanagement.htm). With all these resources you should be able to create your own application with animated transitions.